# How do I determine which camera is left and which camera is right in a stereo camera system using opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I have a calibrated stereo camera pair and this is used to estimate the depth to certain objects using opencv and c++. The cameras are initialised using VideoCapture class by pasing an integer index as follows.

```
VideoCapture capL, capR;
capL.open(0);
capR.open(1);
```

However, camera with index 0 is not always the left camera. Those indices seems to be assigned randomly. How do I determine which camera is the left camera? Assume that the cameras are already calibrated and all the calibration parameters are given.
Currently, I'm on ubuntu and am using opencv 3.4.1 and C++.

Comment: Did you see this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039132/how-to-get-the-port-numbers ?

Comment: @87VNO Thank you. I think this should work for me as well. Will give it a try.